# Are notifications for answers not being sent?

Tags: discussion, bug, notifications

I just noticed that I never received any notifications for the answers posted to one of my [questions](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/413/is-it-possible-to-prompt-google-bard-to-summarize-a-webpages-contents-by-giving)

I did get notifications for comments

Are notifications for answers not being sent?

Comment: This should be tagged [tag:support] instead of [tag:discussion] / [tag:bug].

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if you get the answer notification from this one.

If not then you may want to take a look into your profile's Email Settings.

Maybe your Inbox setting is set to *Weekly*?

This is mine, and it has been working fine.

[image: Inbox]

Comment: Yes this one got a notification immediately thanks for the email settings suggestion i will have to check it out